# Why 予期せぬ is more common than 予期しない?

Tags: morphology

予期{よき}する (to expect) is a nominal verb with two negative forms: 予期せぬ and 予期しない. Why the せぬ form is more common than the more familiar しない?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's simply because It's a *fixed expression* originated from classical Japanese.

We have a number of such expressions. See: [Nuance and conversational use of なきにしもあらず](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42718/5010)