# Meaning of 「かくや（という）」

Tags: particles, set-phrases, archaic-language, particle-や

A quote from [80日間世界一周](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%22%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8F%E3%82%84%E3%81%A8%22):

> 巨大な湖が凍ったら**かくや**という景色だった。
>   *It seemed like a vast frozen lake.*

I'm guessing the [「かく」 is this one](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%96%AF%E3%81%8F), but I don't understand how the 「や」 works. Could this be a set phrase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's short for [かくやあらん](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%96%AF%E3%81%8F%E3%82%84%E3%81%82%E3%82%89%E3%82%93), which is one of the [fixed expressions from archaic Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42724/5010).

- 斯く: "like this"
- や: archaic question marker (eighth definition [here](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%84); grammatical rule [here](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/kobun-adjectives/) and [here](http://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa010037.htm))
- あらん (あらむ in historical kana usage): あり ("to be") + [む](http://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009010.htm) ("to seem; should"). → "should be; to seem to be"

So in modern Japanese, it's このようであろうか or こんな感じだろうか.

かくや is used to give an unrealistic/extreme analogy ([～もかくや](http://yourei.jp/%E3%82%82%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8F%E3%82%84), ～ればかくや, ～ならかくや). Your sentence is a typical example of かくや(あらん).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure if this should be tagged [archaic-language] or [classical-japanese] or even both because that tofugu article is about classical Japanese and if it should be [particle-や] at all (coined the tag...) so feel free to edit them

Comment: @siikamiika I use this word in a set phrase かくやありなん meaning きっとこんなんだよね sometimes, but not so often; more often than きんだい/近大/. 巨大な湖が凍ったら**きっとこんなんだよね**という景色だった。

Comment: @mackygoo So the 「なん」 is [this one](http://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa010031.htm) (emphasis indicator) in the phrase you use? Also I don't really understand the conjugation rules here but is 「あり」 in your example just 連体形 and in かくや**あら**ん something else?