# What does 形ク mean in japanese?

Tags: grammar, classical-japanese, i-adjectives

I was searching for the meaning of  "時すでに遅し。" but I couldn't find 遅し in the dictionary  [goo.ne.jp](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/search.php?kind=all&MT=%E9%81%85%E3%81%97&SH=1&IE=UTF-8) and [weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%81%85%E3%81%97) tells me that it's おそい with 形ク in parenthesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It stands for 形容詞-ク活用【かつよう】. ク活用 is one of the two conjugation types of classical Japanese adjectives. 遅し is the archaic "dictionary" form of modern 遅い. 時すでに遅し is a [fixed set phrase that preserves the archaic grammar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42718/5010). It just means "It is/was too late."

See:

- [Kobun (Classical Japanese) - Adjectives & Musubi](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/kobun-adjectives/)
- [Classical Japanese Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Japanese_language#Adjectives_(%E5%BD%A2%E5%AE%B9%E8%A9%9E_Keiyoushi))