# Understanding 大事なコミュニケーションだと言わんばかりの潔さ

Tags: meaning, parsing

I have trouble understanding the bold part below:

> 人に迷惑を掛ける事へ一切の躊躇がない。**人に迷惑を掛ける事そのものが、大事なコミュニケーションだと言わんばかりの潔さ**。そうだ、アイはこれだった。([source](https://youngjump.jp/oshinoko/novel_45510/novel_03.html))

In particular, I don't understand the meaning of the word 潔さ. It seems to mean something like "resolution." Also, I think I have issues parsing the sentence. 大事なコミュニケーションだと言わんばかりの潔さ doesn't make any sense to me alone, so it would be better to understand 人に迷惑を掛ける事そのものが大事なコミュニケーションだ as a quotation for 言わんばかり, i.e.

> 「人に迷惑を掛ける事そのものが大事なコミュニケーションだ」と言わんばかりの潔さ

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 潔さ【いさぎよさ】 is the noun ("-ness") form of 潔い. [Jisho.org lists](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%BD%94%E3%81%84) seemingly random translations for this word, but the underlying meaning of the word, in my own words, is *"being free from emotions like hesitation, regret, attachment, vengefulness or anxiety that bind you"*.

  > 潔く負けを認めるべきだ。
  > You should accept defeat {promptly / gracefully / cleanly / with dignity / without hesitation}.
  >
  > 彼は難しい状況でも常に潔い決断を下す。
  > He always makes a {clean / decisive} decision when faced with difficult situations.
  >
  > 自分の信念に忠実で潔い生き方
  > a pure way of life staying true to one's beliefs
  >
  > 何も持たない潔い生き方
  > a {simple / minimalistic} way of life without owning anything
  >
  > 引っ越し前に潔くアニメブルーレイを全部処分した。
  > I {bravely / neatly / unhesitatingly} disposed of all my anime Blu-rays before moving.

  潔い is basically a positive word, but in the context in question, 潔さ is used in a sarcastic manner to describe her boldness or (excessive) carefreeness. So it's essentially saying the same thing as 躊躇がない. In some contexts, 潔い can be naturally translated as "graceful", "resolute" or "honorable", but these don't work in this context.
- Yes, the quotative と refers to everything before it in the sentence.
- [言わんばかり](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A8%80%E3%82%8F%E3%82%93%E3%81%B0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8A) is a set phrase meaning "as if to say". This can be analyzed using the grammar of classical Japanese, but [it's probably better to learn it by rote](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42724/5010).

> 「人に迷惑を掛ける事そのものが、大事なコミュニケーションだ」と言わんばかりの潔さ(だ)。
>
> Her boldness is so extreme that it's almost as if she says causing trouble for others in itself is an important form of communication.